# laravel 5 change mysql password

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, change-password

I have the feeling that my mysql database has been hacked by someone doing minor changes (very strange but very annoying).  So I want to change mysql password.  I remember that a while ago and I had some issues (I had to delete a cache to finally get it to work but I don't remember which file).  So I want to be sure that I do it correctly as the site is live.

1. I would change the password of the database.
2. I would edit the .ENV aqnd change it there
3. From the console, I would run the following commands:

   - php artisan cache:clear
   - php artisan config:clear
   - php artisan config:cache
4. Then there is that cache file I need to delete but which one is it?

Is this the correct procedure?

Comment: Why not try it out on your test system to see whether this works? Without knowing more about your application, it's close to impossible to provide an answer

Comment: My test system uses root/blank.  I can not change that.